# How to test a campaign in universal analytics?

Tags: universal-analytics, campaigns

How does one test a campaign (rather than release it to production) in Google Universal Analytics?

Comment: What kind of a campaign are you talking about? Is it manually tagged?

Comment: Do you have a development environment with a separate Analytics profile?

Comment: I have a dev environment, but not a seperate Analytics profile.

Comment: Are you able to create a test property for testing purposes only so as to not pollute the prod data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Create a separate Google Analytics profile for your dev environment.
- Configure your dev server to use a different Google Analytics snippet
- Test your campaign URLs against your dev server
- View realtime analytics to verify that the the campaign parameters do what you want as they come in
- Test the functionality
- The next day view the dev analytics reports and make sure everything was tracked properly